# How to escape & in scp

Tags: shell, escaping, scp

Yes, I do realize it has been asked a thousand of times how to escape **spaces** in scp, but I fail to do that with the *&*-sign, so if that sign is part of the directory name.

```
[sorunome@sorunome-desktop tmp]$ scp test.txt "bpi:/home/sorunome/test & stuff"
zsh:1: command not found: stuff
lost connection
```

The & sign seems to be messing things quite a bit up, using \& won't solve the issue as then the remote directory is not found:

```
[sorunome@sorunome-desktop tmp]$ scp test.txt "bpi:/home/sorunome/test \& stuff"
scp: ambiguous target
```

Not even by omitting the quotes and adding \ all over the place this is working:

```
[sorunome@sorunome-desktop tmp]$ scp test.txt bpi:/home/sorunome/test\ \&\ stuff
zsh:1: command not found: stuff
lost connection
```

So, any idea?

Comment: Must you use zsh? I tried under bash and it worked without any additional escaping.

Comment: No I don't have to use zsh, I just tried it with bash and it yields the same effects (instead of it saying "zsh:1" it now says "bash")

Also, just for being so interested I just tried    `scp test.txt "bpi:/home/sorunome/test & touch test.tmp"`
and it does actually create the file test.tmp in my remote home!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Escaping both the spaces and the ampersand did the trick for me :

```
scp source_file "user@host:/dir\ with\ spaces\ \&\ ampersand"
```

The quotes are still needed for some reason.

Comment: Weird, this seems to be working! Any idea on how I can add that to a variable in a bash script, though?

Comment: This seems to be doing it: `scp "$(sprintf %q "$local")" "$(sprintf %q "$remote")"`

Comment: The quotes are needed to protect the backslashes themselves. `scp` is a bit tricky because the arguments are processed twice: once by the local shell prior to running `scp`, and *again* after the file names are sent to the remote host. (It might help to think of `scp` as a wrapper around something like `cat source_file | ssh user@host 'cat > "/dir with spaces & ampersand"'`

Answer (score 0):

When using scp or cp, special characters can break the file path. You get around this by escaping the special character.

Using cp you can use the normal method of escaping special characters, which is preceding it with a backslash. For example, a path with a space could be copied using:

`cp photo.jpg My\ Pictures/photo.jpg`

The remote path in scp doesn’t work escaping using this method. You need to escape the special characters using a double backslash. Using the same example, the My Photos folder would have its space escaped using:

`scp photo.jpg "user@remotehost:/home/user/My\\ Photos/photo.jpg"`

The double quotes are also important, the whole path with the special characters must be enclosed with double quotes.

Source : https://dominichosler.wordpress.com/2011/08/27/using-scp-with-special-characters/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to escape `%` use `%%`

Answer (score 0):

Surround the file name in an additional pair of `\"` like this:

```
scp "test.txt" "bpi:/home/sorunome/\"test & stuff\""
```

Since nothing needs to change inside the file name, this can be directly applied to variables:

```
scp "$local" "bpi:/home/sorunome/\"$remote\""
```

The outer quotes (`"`) are interpreted by the local shell. The inner quotes (`\"`) are interpreted on the remote server. Thanks to @chepner for pointing out how the arguments are processed twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
function escape_file() {
    local ESCAPED=$(echo "$1" | sed -E 's:([ ()[!&<>"$*,;=?@\^`{}|]|]):\\\1:g' | sed -E "s/([':])/\\\\\1/g")
    echo "$ESCAPED"
}
REMOTE_FILE="/tmp/Filename with & symbol's! (xxx) [1.8, _aaa].gz"
scp "server:$(escape_ "$REMOTE_FILE")" /tmp/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).